# how to avoid white in the distance after alt + tab

Tags: technical-issues, world-of-warcraft

Sometimes I need to <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> out of the game to do stuff, and I've noticed that after doing this the distant view turns completely white. For example in stormwind where the boats are, the background in the distance on the horizon goes white and this even reflects on the water, it doesn't look right, specially at night.

Usually it's a darker colour or at least something that looks like it belongs there depending of the time of day in game.

What can I do about this? The only way I know to deal with it is to quit the game and launch it again.

I am playing on windows 8.1 with most recent updates from windows update. I use an nvidia gtx 690 graphics card. I play the game full screen at 2560 x 1600 with all the settings at ultra.

Here are some screenshots of the anomaly
[image: docks in stormwind]

[image: waiting for a boat]

[image: happens in kalimdor too]

Comment: Have you tried playing with the game in Windowed (Fullscreen) mode?

Comment: Switiching to windows full screen does not remove the problem after it has occured. I have yet to experiment fully with all the combinations, but I feel that this issue arises after the first alt + tab, I can't remember when this started, perhaps it's a problem that has been there for a long time.on the other hand perhaps it occured when the graphics were updated for cataclysm

Comment: I'm not suggesting using to fix it once it's already happened - if you turn on Windowed (Fullscreen) mode and then restart the game client, does tabbing out still cause distant terrain to be untextured? I recall when I used to play that tabbing out used to cause some visual oddities in Fullscreen mode that didn't occur in Windowed (Fullscreen) mode.

Comment: No. Thank you! I guess I could play in windowed full screen mode from now on. Though I tend to think that it uses more resources and gives a lower framerate.

Comment: I think Blizzard added an option, possibly in MoP, that allows you to limit the framerate of the game while it's not the active window, which should lower consumption at least while you're tabbed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the game in Windowed (Fullscreen) mode will (often) prevent issues linked to alt-tabbing out of the client. Restart the client in Windowed (Fullscreen) mode and try tabbing out again.

An alternative option is to try updating/rolling back your graphics drivers. Lastly, if none of that helps, it's time to file a bug report with Blizzard so that they can look into a fix for it.